# How to remove a 'temporary' id after using it as an href?

Tags: jquery

I have created a 'backButton' to take a user back to the text/link that brought them to an image on the same page.
(I have given the 'backButton anchor' `href="#BackToLink"`).

When an anchor link is clicked on, it is given the `id` of `BackToLink`.
(I have also given a 'class' of 'que', which adds 'padding-top' in CSS so it will be visible below the 'fixed-position' header):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'BackToLink').attr('class', 'que');  
});
```

I now need to figure out how/ where/ when to remove the 'id' of 'backToLink' from one anchor link, so that I can then apply it to the next one that is clicked on. ( It currently just takes me back to the first one).

Maybe: 
`$('a').removeAttr('id', 'BackToLink');`
but I can't find the right place to use it.

Comment: You can already remove the ID with the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

Passing IDs around for elements is not optimal. I'd recommend using classes for this.

Anyway, if you just want to remove the ID, you can easily do this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#BackToLink').removeAttr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', 'BackToLink').attr('class', 'que');
});
```

This minimal example illustrates the behavior. Green color indicates which class had the `BackToLink` id, bold is the a with the class `que`, which because it is not removed is applied to every element that is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#BackToLink').removeAttr('id');
    $(this).attr('id', 'BackToLink').attr('class', 'que');
  })
})
```

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}
#BackToLink {
  color: green;
}
.que {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

Comment: That is not working. I also tried this:
  $('a').click(function(){
   
   $('a').not(this).removeAttr('id');
   
   $(this).attr('id', 'backToLink').attr('class', 'que');
       
  });
Not working.

I attempted giving each link an id, and putting it inside a variable. But when I tried to use the variable, it just kept passing the name of the variable into the href.

Comment: @GarySr Then I am not sure if I understand the question. I've understood it as you want to remove the old object that has the ID "BackToLink"? My code should do that.

Comment: OptimusCrime I would like to just remove the ID which is assigned to that link when clicking on it. That way when I click on another link to another image, that link will now have that ID. When the backButton is clicked it will take the user back to his place in the text.

Comment: @GarySr You need to rewrite your question and come with better examples. I am not able to understand how you wan this to function. Also, fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: OptimusCrime To your first point - 'Passing IDs around for elements is not optimal', the more I attempt to make it work, the more I tend to agree. I will take a different approach, then come back at a later date and attempt  a better explanation of what I am trying to do. Thanks for you response.